# Coalescing a subset to its parent set

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, coalesce

I have two tables, A and B. B is a random subset of A but with some values that override the default values in A. How do I join the two tables to coalesce their values?

A

```
1, 0
2, 0
3, 0
4, 0
```

B

```
2, 10
3, 11
```

Output

```
1, 0
2, 10
3, 11
4, 0
```

Here is my actual query - I thought I could do this with LEFT OUTER JOIN, but this restricts the Output set to the intersection of A and B rows. I need all A rows to return, coalesced with the relevant B rows.

```
SELECT A.factor, A.categorical_value, coalesce(A.positive, B.positive),  coalesce(A.negative, B.negative) 
FROM features A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN profiles B ON (A.factor=B.factor AND A.categorical_value=B.categorical_value)
WHERE B.uuid='9e5083da74305628336631da9d2903e3'
```

As Craig Ringer points out below, I am inadvertently restricting A with my B clause. But then how do I do this? Table A is a many-to-many table of profile attributes, where uuid indicates the user id. Table B is a master list of all possible profile attributes. I want the query to return the master list with the an individual profile superimposed on to it.

Comment: You want `a LEFT OUTER JOIN b`, then `coalesce`.

Comment: Thank you! Question updated in response...

Comment: In which table is the `uuid` column?

Comment: uuid is in B. And apologies - I had my example A, B reversed. I just fixed that (same result - only returns B).

Comment: " but this restricts the Output set to the intersection of A and B rows". No, it doesn't. I think you might need to show the table definitions that go along with the real query, and some of the real data, because a left outer join most certainly does not restrict the rows of the left side. That's pretty much the definition. Your problem appears to be that you then have a `where` clause on `B.uuid` that can never be true unless there is a non-null value for `B`; thus, you've effectively turned your `left outer join` into an `inner join`.

Comment: Sheiza, you are right. Duh. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### After question update:

As [@Craig already informed you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679274/coalescing-a-subset-to-its-parent-set/22679565?noredirect=1#comment34566642_22679274), a `WHERE` condition on `B` would only select matching rows in `B` and act like a `[INNER] JOIN` instead of a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`.

You need to pull that `WHERE` condition up **into the condition of the `LEFT JOIN`**.
While being at it, I opportunistically simplified with `USING`, since all joining column names are identical. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

Information is still incomplete and contradicting. Here is another educated guess:

```
SELECT a.factor, a.categorical_value
     , COALESCE(a.positive, b.positive) AS positive
     , COALESCE(a.negative, b.negative) AS negative 
FROM   features a 
LEFT  JOIN profiles b USING (factor, categorical_value, uuid)
WHERE  a.uuid='9e5083da74305628336631da9d2903e3'
```

Not sure if you need to join on `udid`, too.
Your example would indicate `COALESCE(b.positive, a.positive)`. Something does not add up ...

#### More updates in comment

Adapt your JOIN condition then:

```
SELECT a.factor, a.categorical_value
     , COALESCE(a.positive, b.positive) AS positive
     , COALESCE(a.negative, b.negative) AS negative 
FROM   features a 
LEFT   JOIN profiles b ON a.factor = b.factor
                      AND a.categorical_value = b.categorical_value
                      AND b.uuid='9e5083da74305628336631da9d2903e3';
```

Comment: Apologies, I did not completely state my question. I have updated it to reflect why this suggestion, which was my first attempt at solution, did not work. Thank you for cleaning up my question!

Comment: @metalaureate: The question is still incomplete. I added another version.

Comment: I am not worthy of the help, but thank you. The remaining problem is that my left joined table does not contain uuid. It's the template for profiles, but profiles contains multiple different subsets, individuated by uuid.

Comment: I am mixed up, sorry. A does not contain uuid. Only B. I want to select the relevant profile in B and merge it onto A.